# Callback function after user selects OTP using From Messages in Angular 13 app on an iPhone

Tags: angular, autocomplete, autofill

I want to invoke a callback function after user touches on the OTP code received as the suggestion from keypad via sms on iPhone in chrome browser as shown in below image

[image]

Currently, once user touches From Messages, complete 380711 is filled only in the first input field instead of filling each digit in each individual field. So I want a way to invoke a callback function after user touches the keypad and then I can clear first field and display value in each of the fields. Can someone please help me with this issue?